# How does $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/f\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have quite easy question. Is working in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/ f\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ the same as working in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ modulo polynomial $f$ ($\in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$)? I have quite problems with the intuition in factor-(-rings, -algebras...)

Thanks

Comment: This depends: what do you understand by "working in $\;\Bbb Z_2[x]\;$ modulo a polynomial"? The ring $\;\Bbb Z_2[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ is a quotient ring, and its elements are left (or right: as you with) cosets of that ideal in the polynomial ring.

Comment: I meant if those two things are somehow equivalent

Comment: Thank you. I just tried to make clear that I don't  know what "two things" you mean. Working with cosets in quotient rings is something I understand, working in the polynomial ring (*not* in the quotient!) "modulo a polynomial" is not that clear to me, that's all.

Comment: My understanding is that the two concepts (constructs) are perfectly equivalent. Even more than that, maybe: different ways of describing the same thing.